# How to split a file based on headers

Tags: java

I'm using a `BufferedReader` to read from a file that looks like this:

```
BASE
<x coord : double> <y coord : double> 
SOLDIER_POINT
<x coord : double > <y coord : double > 
DESTINATION
<x coord : double > <y coord : double >
<x coord : double > <y coord : double > 
******
```

How can I split this file? I only need the data after each header.

This is where I am right now:

```
    BufferedReader bfr;
    String lineObtained = null;

    try {
        bfr = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
        lineObtained = bfr.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

I'm then going to use the data to populate an array (i know how to do this, just don't know how to split)

Comment: What do you mean by *"split this file"*, Split it into what? Are you asking how to read and parse the content into coordinate pairs of `double` values?

Comment: @Andreas Yes exactly, I've never done this before so not sure :/

Comment: You only want the lines of the file that start with `<x coord`, correct? Also, what do you want to do with these lines?

Comment: You should use a try-with-resources block so the BufferedReader is closed. Do you want only the first point after each header, or all the points? The first two have just one point each, but destination has two.

Comment: @Abra Hi, yep that is correct, I'll then add these lines into an array. I'm just stuck on how to actually get the lines

Comment: @DavidConrad In the first two, i want the first point, but in the destination i want two

Answer (score 0):

To parse that file, you could do something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Point2D>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
    List<Point2D> list = null;
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        int idx = line.indexOf(' ');
        if (idx == -1) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            if (map.putIfAbsent(line, list) != null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate section: " + line);
        } else if (list == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("First line of file must be a section header");
        } else {
            try {
                list.add(new Point2D.Double(Double.parseDouble(line.substring(0, idx)),
                                            Double.parseDouble(line.substring(idx + 1))));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid coordinate line: " + line, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
map.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Sample `test.txt`*

```
BASE
22.79 92
SOLDIER_POINT
71.91 27.35
DESTINATION
97.07 53.36
27.4 56.22
45.71 36.53
```

*Output*

```
BASE=[Point2D.Double[22.79, 92.0]]
SOLDIER_POINT=[Point2D.Double[71.91, 27.35]]
DESTINATION=[Point2D.Double[97.07, 53.36], Point2D.Double[27.4, 56.22], Point2D.Double[45.71, 36.53]]
```

Comment: Assuming the header lines don't contain a space. Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: @Abra With the example given, where the second header uses underscore instead of space, then yes, it is a valid *assumption*. Still an assumption though, and only OP can say for sure. This is just example code of how it *could* be done. We don't know the form OP really want the resulting data in, so it cannot be more than an example of one way to do it, for OP to use as a template for the real code.

Answer (score -1):

There is a string method called split. The string will be split based on a given regular expression.
If you want to split the sections you have to define what makes a line a header (uppercase characters?). If the headers are not a distinct set you may use a map to store them.